# How could particles with electric charge be massless before the electroweak symmetry breaking?

Tags: mass, charge, electroweak

How could particles with electric charge be massless before the electroweak symmetry breaking? Wouldn't the energy stored in the electric field contribute to the mass of the particle?

Comment: possible duplicates: [Massless charged particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7905/84967), [Why cannot massless particles carry charges?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/200375/84967) and links therein.